# file upload system

Tags: php, file-upload

Does anyone know of the file upload system which I can use for my application which is either open source or can be purchased?

I need to be able to upload file/s to the web server and send out email links to users to download the files?

I really need this to be an 'all in one' solution where I can just install/setup as i'm not really a developer!

a bit like http://www.yousendit.com/

Don't mind which language any is fine.

Comment: If you are interested in the 'complete solution' this question belongs at superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any idea what the technology requirement is? PHP, ASP.NET etc?

A while ago I remember taking a look at the following for an ASP.NET application I was developing.

http://ajaxuploader.com/

Although it isn't an all in one solution it does contain samples which are ready for use with minor tweaks. You might need to develop a page to show a list of all uploaded files though as I'm personally not aware of a 'complete solution'.